# How to use jQuery the Angular way inside a directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building a [chartist](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) Directive for my AngularJS app. What breaks my understanding at the moment is how I integrate jQuery code the Angular way.

This framework is using jQuery for creating a tooltip. The code is right here:

```
  var $chart = $('.ct-chart');

  var $toolTip = $chart
    .append('<div class="tooltip"></div>')
    .find('.tooltip')
    .hide();

  $chart.on('mouseenter', '.ct-point', function() {
    var $point = $(this);
    var value = $point.attr('ct:value');
    $toolTip.html(value).show();
  });

  $chart.on('mouseleave', '.ct-point', function() {
    $toolTip.hide();
  });

  $chart.on('mousemove', function(event) {
    $toolTip.css({
      left: (event.offsetX || event.originalEvent.layerX) - $toolTip.width() / 2 - 10,
      top: (event.offsetY || event.originalEvent.layerY) - $toolTip.height() - 40
    });
  });
```

My question is: How should I translate this to an AngularJS way of doing things?

1. I'm getting an element from the DOM
2. Adding a new element to it
3. And then have interactions with this newly added element

> What would be the way Angular is handling those things? Is a 1:1
>   "translation" approbate or should I put ngHide, ngMouseenter inside
>   the view?

Comment: JQuery can be used inside Controller, you just need to keep you bindings updated using $scope.$apply.

Comment: I know, but in the documentation, in every book they say: If you use jQuery, you are doing probably something wrong. So I wonder if I can use just the Angular API for those things.

Comment: `var $chart = $('.ct-chart');` rather than getting elements like this, you get $element directly in your directives. so its kinda angularjs finds the element for you and give you its handle...

Comment: once you have parent element adding new element is very similar to jquery only thing is to do : $comple($parent.$scope) to get the stuff binded correctly

Comment: I recommend that you use bootstrap tooltips rather than jquery toolips - better integration with angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `$` with `angular.element` which is the same as `$` of JQuery

& the other problem is before adding any new element to angular DOM it should go through the $compile cycle, Otherwise angular will not register that part of DOM

**Code**

```
  var $chart = $('.ct-chart');

  var $toolTip = $chart
    .append($compile('<div class="tooltip"></div>')(scope))  //compiling newly added element
    .find('.tooltip')
    .hide();

  $chart.on('mouseenter', '.ct-point', function() {
    var $point = $(this);
    var value = $point.attr('ct:value');
    $toolTip.html(value).show();
  });

  $chart.on('mouseleave', '.ct-point', function() {
    $toolTip.hide();
  });

  $chart.on('mousemove', function(event) {
    $toolTip.css({
      left: (event.offsetX || event.originalEvent.layerX) - $toolTip.width() / 2 - 10,
      top: (event.offsetY || event.originalEvent.layerY) - $toolTip.height() - 40
    });
  });
```

All other code looks fine to me.

Comment: `$('.ct-chart')` and `angular.element(".ct-chart")` are not the same. In angular.element, we can't use selectors

Comment: @mohamedrias You can, if jQuery is included. If it's not you cannot select elements anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery style code inside AngularJs.For example getting DOM element, you can use Jquery syntax,but Angular has it's syntax to do that.With angular.element([selector]).It returns you the same thing,which Jquery does.One thing else.If you mousevent functions are not defined as angularjs scope function,you don't have to $compile the template.